# Postgres LIKE %% syntax errors

Tags: postgresql, syntax, syntax-error, filtering

I have been trying to do a `LIKE` comparison in postgres but repeatedly receive an error telling me that the column `"%@firstname%"` doesn't exist.

I should clarify, this query is executed in a function, "@firstname" is the parameter passed into the function.

The relevant section of the query is below:

`WHERE u."firstname" LIKE "%@firstname%"`

I do not want an exact comparison which is why I am trying to add the %% to the query. It works just fine without them for exact queries. Whenever, I add the % then it assumes that they are part of the variable name and subsequently can't find it.

I have also tried the following:

1. `'%"@firstname"%'` which results in an empty array being returned even though it should have matched
2. `"%'@firstname'%"` which results in `error: column "%'@filter'%" does not exist`
3. `%"@firstname"%` which results in `error: column "%'@filter'%" does not exist`

Comment: Use single quote ' not double quote " for string

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek I now clarified in the question but "@firstname" is a function parameter, so it requires double quotes. I tried to circumvent this by doing this `'%"@firstname"%'` but that turns the entire variable into 1 string, no longer containing the varaible

Comment: You should avoid the use of quoted identifiers. They make your life much more complicated than it should be.

Answer (score 3):

If `"@firstname"` is a parameter you need something like:

```
WHERE u.firstname LIKE concat('%', "@firstname", '%');
```

Comment: I tried FORMAT() just before reading this and it worked but I vastly prefer the CONCAT() syntax.